# Problem with rendering objects on the template Django

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to make a filter on my ecommerce website. I am taking a data using json from the user and filtering items on the views.py. There are no any errors and I can see the filtered products on the console. However, I can not render products on the template. It is not giving any errors. It's just not showing.
**views.py**

```
def Products(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']
    products = Product.objects.all()
    gender = Gender.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    product_types = ProductType.objects.all()
    try:

        data = json.loads(request.body)

        productTId = data['productTId']
        productVId = data['productVId']
        genderId = data['genderId']
        
        genderId = get_object_or_404(Gender, id=genderId)
        productVId = get_object_or_404(Category, id=productVId)
        productTId = get_object_or_404(ProductType, id=productTId)
        
        filtered_products = Product.objects.filter(typeP=productTId).filter(category=productVId).filter(Gender=genderId)
        countFilter=filtered_products.count()
        print(filtered_products)
        print(countFilter)
        return JsonResponse(filtered_products, safe = False)
    except:
        None

    try:
        
        context = {'countFilter':countFilter,'filtered_products':filtered_products,'gender':gender,'categories':categories,'product_types':product_types,'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems, 'order':order, 'items':items}
    except:
        context = {'gender':gender,'categories':categories,'product_types':product_types,'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems, 'order':order, 'items':items}
    return render(request, 'product.html', context)
```

**html**

```
{% for product in filtered_products %}
            <div class="card">
    <div class="card__img">
        <picture><source srcset="{{product.imageURL}}" type="image/webp"><img src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt=""></picture>
    </div>
    <h6 class="card__title">{{product.name}}</h6>
    <div class="card__descr">{{product.description}}...
        <div class="card__more" onclick="More('{{product.id}}')">подробнее...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card__func">
        <a class="btn-hover card__button-buy update-cart" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add">В КОРЗИНУ</a>
        <div class="card__right">
            <div class="card__price" data-product="{{product.id}}">{{product.price}} р</div>
            <div class="card__changed-price card__changed-price--card">
                <div class="card__changed-btn card__changed-btn--prev card__changed-btn--max increase" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="minus"><svg width="8" height="2" viewBox="0 0 8 2" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M1 1L7 1" stroke="#7ABC51" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <p class="card__changed-thing" id="quantity" class="quantity" data-product="{{product.id}}">1</p>
                <div  class="card__changed-btn card__changed-btn--next increase" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="plus"><svg width="8" height="8" viewBox="0 0 8 8" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M3 7C3 7.41421 3.33579 7.75 3.75 7.75C4.16421 7.75 4.5 7.41421 4.5 7V4.75H6.75C7.16421 4.75 7.5 4.41421 7.5 4C7.5 3.58579 7.16421 3.25 6.75 3.25H4.5V1C4.5 0.585786 4.16421 0.25 3.75 0.25C3.33579 0.25 3 0.585786 3 1V3.25H0.75C0.335786 3.25 0 3.58579 0 4C0 4.41421 0.335786 4.75 0.75 4.75H3V7Z" fill="#7ABC51"/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
As I mentioned it's not returning any errors and I can see result on the console. But, it's only not showing while I tried to render it. Hope for your response.
```

Comment: It seems to call the except  line that has no filtered_products

Comment: But if I put print on the try it's showing queryset of filtered products on the console. Also it's not giving any errors while loading a template

Comment: I think one of the objects inside the context has issue try to cross-check it